# SQL Server 2008 conversion failed

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a simple count of the CPT codes and am confused on why I am getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'J1040' to data type int.

Here is the query:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT   
    count(pvp.CPTCode) as CPTcount

from 
    PatientVisitProcs pvp 
    JOIN    batch b ON pvp.batchid = b.batchid
    JOIN    patientvisit ar ON pvp.patientvisitid = ar.patientvisitid 

WHERE   

    b.Entry >= ISNULL('09/01/2012','1/1/1900') and b.Entry < dateadd(d, 1, ISNULL('8/31/2012','1/1/3000'))
    and pvp.CPTCode in (62311,64484,64493,64494,62310,64479,64480,64490,64491,64492,64633,64634,64635,64636) 
    AND  --Filter on company
    (
    ( ar.CompanyID IN (1725))
    )
    AND  --Filter on facility
    (
    ( ar.FacilityID IN (1460))
    )
Group By pvp.CPTCode
With RollUp
```

A gentle push or swift kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. THanks!

I believe it is coming from the actual CPTCode column:

```
CPTCode
80053
80061
83721
85025
81001
84153
Copay
Copay
J0152
```

Comment: What column has the value `J1040`?  Create table statements and sample data would be helpful.

Comment: `OR (NULL IS NULL)`   Should this be there?  Its tossing out the result of your `CompanyID` comparison.

Comment: If the data for `CPTCode` is a varchar, then you should enclose the values from your IN clause in single quotes.  i.e.  `pvp.CPTCode in ('62311','64484',`

Comment: Nope null is not null should not ahve been there. I am modifying an existing query and forgot to take it out. I took it out of the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
pvp.CPTCode in (62311,64484,64493,64494,62310,64479,64480,64490,64491,64492,64633,64634,64635,64636)
```

But your column type is varchar(n).  So try changing it to:

```
pvp.CPTCode in ('62311','64484','64493','64494','62310','64479','64480'...  and so forth
```

Comment: That got rid of the error message, but returned no data. Something is still wrong with it. Hmm maybe my id is wrong for facility. HAHA my date is wrong. Whoops, had 2012 instead of 2013. Thank you guys for your help. I really appreciate it : )

Comment: Go forth, @user2588088, and use your SQL powers for great awesome.